# Debug Glassfish file Authentication

Tags: authentication, glassfish-3

Glassfish basic file authentication fails me with:

```
message Access to the requested resource has been denied

description Access to the specified resource (Access to the requested resource has been denied) has been forbidden.
```

I think I did everything right but obviously I did not. Has anybody got any ideas on how to debug the authentication process?

Comment: Have you had any success in debugging this?

Comment: You can tweak the logging — but I am still fighting the with the system. For details see below

Comment: Yeah, that's about as far as I got.  However, it has recently been discussed on the glassfish forum: http://java.net/projects/glassfish/lists/users/archive/2011-06/message/21

Comment: What web framework are you using?  I am using lift.

Comment: http://snippetspace.com/projects/iwebkit/ — which is a good an none at all ;-). But I do use Scala as well. And EJBs for the businesses logic.

Answer (score 1):

After more experimenting I found that the following line in `config\logging.properties` gives a few extra informations:

```
javax.enterprise.system.core.security.level=FINEST
```

Still debugging authentication is a pain and if someone knows how to get more informations I would be grateful.